# Java Send Mail Function

Tags: java, sendmail

Does anybody has a proper java send mail function that works 100 % and can share it with me. I am getting some problem with mine!!!

Comment: looks like you didn't finish the question

Comment: @Robert: He wanted to, but he was busy getting some p.

Comment: He just accidentally the submit button

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Java developer by trade, but [Java Mail](http://www.google.com/search?q=send+email+in+java) seems to do the job quite nicely.  The "works 100%" requirement is going to depend a lot on your implementation and on the availability of the mail server.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check [Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) package from Jakarta. It provides higher level and more user friendly API on top of Java mail API.